# Structure for calling child pages

Tags: child-pages

In my project, I want the parent page to display 3 child pages in its menu.
Every child page will be different from product to product.

> ```
> For example Product 1(Parent) 
>  -Product 1
>    -Overview
>    -Details
>    -Pricing
>  -Product 2 
>    -Overview....
> ```

Each product will have the same template, I guess, but how can I display different child pages with the same name, since I dynamically load my child pages to the menu of the parent? Code to generate children :

```
<div class="col-md-12 product-navigation">

            <?php
                if ($post->post_parent) {
                    $page = $post->post_parent;
                } 
                else {
                    $page = $post->ID;
                }

                $children = wp_list_pages(array(
                    'child_of' => $page,
                    'echo' => '0',
                    'title_li' => ''
                ));

                if ($children) {
                    echo "<ul class='genProductList'>\n".$children."</ul>\n";
                } 

            ?>
        </div>
```

Comment: How are you creating and linking these child pages? Can we see your code so far?

Comment: @TomJNowell i edited my post, check that!